# How to sum different rows of different keys in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 \n
A    | 1    | 1 \n
B    | 23   | 2 \n
C    | 21   | 1 \n
```

Is it doable in Pandas to add, combine or sum A & B together so it will be like:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 \n
A    | 24   | 3 \n
C    | 21   | 1 \n
```

I tried group by but it won't work since there are different keys A and B involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) for same categories and then `groupby` + `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(df['Col1'].replace({'B':'A'})).sum().reset_index()  
print (df)
  Col1  Col2  Col3
0    A    24     3
1    C    21     1
```

Comment: Cool i didn't think of replacing. nice one!